# PHP Regex find + alter + replace within each tag

Tags: php, regex

I am new to regex if this is indeed what I need.

The string might include :

```
[name* your-name ]

[email* your-main-email some_thing]

etc
```

Amateur logic :

1. Search string for '['
2. get substring between this and next ']'
3. extract hyphenated word (probably find first word between first and next space)
4. Replace substring with hyphenated word
5. Repeat with all remaining tags

To hopefully produce :

```
[your-name]

[your-main-email]

etc
```

Or am I off target with method?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$str = '[name* your-name ] [email* your-main-email some_thing]';
$str = preg_replace("/\[[^\s]+\s+([^\]\s]+)\s+[^\]]*\]/", "[$1]", $str);
echo $str;
```

Regex explanation:

- `/` Delimiter
- `\[` Match starting square bracket
- `[^\s]+` Match one or more non-space character
- `\s+` Match one or more space
- `(` Start capturing group
- `[^\]\s]+` Match one or more character that is **not** space and **not** `]`
- `)` End capturing group
- `\s+` Match one or more space
- `[^\]]*` Match zero or more character that is **not** `]`
- `\]` Match closing square bracket
- `/` Delimiter

#### Edit

To do replace when last space is missing i.e. `[name* your-name]` then use following regex

```
/\[[^\s]+\s+([^\]\s]+)[^\]]*\]/
```

Comment: Amazing. Could I possibly ask a secondary... What if the last space is missing and could only be a ']' so space/] to test against ?

Comment: Many thanks for this. Makes large forms in contactForm7 a breeze when having to format the email out... now I can just copy the form itself. Best